# printing hash of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash of hash of hash of hash:

```
 $hash{$lengths}{$orfs}{$starts}{$ends} = 1;
```

I don't want to output the entire hash, so I don't want to use data::Dumper.

What I want to do, is output all $orfs that have $lengths of 2678

But when I do:

```
print "$hash{'2678'}";
```

I get as output:

```
HASH(0xa4a298)
```

What am I doing wrong?

what I want are the values in $orfs that are specific to $length 2678, rather than their location...

Comment: I don't want to use Dumper, as that will give me the rest of the entire hash. I literally just want whatever is held within $orfs.
Dumper will give me all of {$orfs}{$starts}{$ends} => 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) on a hashref:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper($hash{'2678'});
```

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2534803/matt) pointed out, if you just want the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) of a hashref, use:

```
print keys %{$hash{'2678'}};
```

Finally, for additional tips check the [`Perl Data Structures Cookbook`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: I don't want to use Dumper, as that will give me the rest of the entire hash. I literally just want whatever is held within $orfs. Dumper will give me all of {$orfs}{$starts}{$ends} => 1

Comment: I think he just wants to print the keys in `$hash{'2678'}`. Something like `print keys $hash{'2678'};`.

Comment: ^haha yea that's what I wanted.... In hindsight that seemed... very obvious.... thanks!!

Comment: Ok, then you want `keys %{$hash{'2678'}}`